# Custom android style won't allow ints?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I am attempting to create a custom android "style" xml. And while everyone else I see out there seems to be using ints, it wont even compile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style  name="DialogStyle"
            parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            >
        <item name="android:background">@color/ReliantCyan</item>
        <item name="android:radius">6</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

gets me:

```
 .../dialogStyle.xml:7: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'android:radius' with value '6').
```

I have also tried `6pd` and `6px` but then it says no strings allowed. What am I doing wrong here?

(any accepted answer must be android 2.2 compatible.)

---

I have now also tried:

```
<dimen name="dRadius">10pd</dimen>
```

and then

```
<item name="android:radius">@dimen/dRadius</item>
```

but I get a very similar error:

```
 ... error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'dRadius' with value '10pd').
```

Comment: You said `6pd`, did you mean `6dp`? Also, try using a dimension resource. Set it above like `<dimen name="testradius">6dp</dimen>` and reference it below using `@dimen/testradius`.

Comment: yeah `6dp`. So does that mean that making a style requires a minimum of 2 files?

Comment: No, the `dimen` could be in the same file. (Above the `style` tag.) Also, you entered `'10pd'`. It needs to be `dp`.

Comment: @Eric that worked. Please post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Done! Glad you've solved it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't explain this behavior, exactly. Specifying `<item name="android:radius">6dp</item>` should be enough.

However, to work around this, we can add a dimension resource (within the same file, even, as long as it's outside of the `style` tag), then use that via `@dimen`.

Something like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="testradius">6dp</dimen>
    <style ...>
        ...
        <item name="android:radius">@dimen/testradius</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

Make sure to specify it as `6dp` (`6px` should work also), not `6` or `6pd` or any variant thereof.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong on this, but i think your declaration should be

android:radius="6dp"